# JQuery interactive map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

A JQuery neewbie here having a bit of a headache making a JQuery solution.

I am trying to make an interactive map of the world. The user is able to mouseover a marker (spesific spot on the map), which makes a info box fadeIn with the name and some information about the place. As i leave the marker with the cursor, the box fadesOut again.

The code under is the html markup with anchor tags for the country Norway, the same with f example Germany, Italy, Britian and so on, but with different positions of course.

```
<div id="mapWrapper">
    <div id="map_container">
        <a class="marker" style="top:14%; left:34%;" data-info="norway"></a>
        <div class="info_box"></div>
        <div class="info" id="norway">
        <h2>Norway - Scandinavia</h2> 
            lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
    </div>
</div>
        <a class="marker" style="top:10%; left:55%;" data-info="iran"></a>
        <div class="info_box"></div>
        <div class="info" id="iran">
        <h2>Iran Republic - Asia</h2> 
            lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
    </div>
</div>
```

The JQuery so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.marker').mouseover(function(){
        var $link = $(this);
        var countryName = $link.data('info');
        var linkPosition = $link.position();
        var infoBoxTopPos = linkPosition.top - 130 + "px";
        var infoBoxLeftPos = linkPosition.left - 120+ "px";
        var container = $('.info' + '#' + countryName).html();
        $('a.marker').removeClass('current');
        $link.addClass('current');
        $('.info_box').html(container).css({
            'top' : infoBoxTopPos,
            'left' : infoBoxLeftPos
        }).show();
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        /*$('.info_box').fadeOut(100);*/
    });
});
```

The problem here is, whenever i hover over a marker, it gives me 2 identical info boxes, instead of only 1. As i inspect it with Firebug, both boxes are of the same div. I know that ive `display:none` it from CSS, so could it be that when JQuery runs, it displays a new .info_box, as well as the "hidden" one? Because of the `addCLass` maybe?

As you can see in the image below, the white marker with the info_box over it is correct, but i dont see why the 2nd info_box appears down to the right?

[image]

I am a bit confused and rather stuck at the moment, i cant seem to "get it".

Any help, tips or tricks would be universally appreciated.

Comment: If you have the info in the DOM already, then why are you creating a new element in the first place?

Comment: How many `.info_box` are on the page? `$(".info_box")` will return a collection so you need to ensure you are setting the html for the correct instance.

Comment: As of now, theres only 2 countries, Norway and Iran, both of them has the `div class="info_box"`, so a total of 2 boxes on the page.

Answer (score 0):

This should not be a problem once the box u wnat to show have a uniq ue I'd.

Step1

Creat all div u want to use in the map and give them the same classname but different I'd set this class aa to be display none
Eg

```
 <div class"aa" id="norway" >
norway is a nice country
</div>
```

Step2

The so called marker, u can use html button for it style it with css to make it beautiful. And give it a value eg
    Norway

Step 3

Jquery will look like this

```
$("body").on('mouseover','.marker',function()

{

$('.aa').hide();

$("#"+this.value).show();

});
```